# Site Redirection with htaccess creates an infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Currently we have a number of sites hosted in one GoDaddy account. Each site is inside a separate folder and their respective domains are bound to those folders. The problem is that our main site is in the root of the host and our primary domain is linked to this root. The problem with this setup is that if for example, one of my other sites is in a folder called "secondsite", I can reach the website by going to www.secondsite.com (which is fine) but ALSO by going to www.mainsite.com/secondsite, which we absolutely not want.

The idea is to move all the files of the main site to a folder of their own (let's call it "mainsite"). When I talked to GoDaddy they told me to do a 301 redirect to that folder. I have never worked with .htaccess but I looked up how to redirect and found that I needed to write this:

Redirect 301 / http://mainsite.com/mainsite

However if I do that when I try to access the website I get infinite redirection: http://mainsite.com/mainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsitemainsite

I've looked online and tried to use other solutions, like

RedirectPermanent / http://mainsite.com/mainsite

but the effect is the same.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Redirect`, you're linking path-nodes together, So:

```
Redirect / /abc/
```

means, anything **starting with** `/` will go to `/abc/`, e.g.:

```
/ -> /abc/
/foo -> /abc/foo
/1/2/3/4/5 -> /abc/1/2/3/4/5
```

And thus, since you're redirecting *back* to the same host, the `/` captures everything and you've got an infinite loop.

Try using either `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!mainsite)(.*)$ /mainsite/$1
```

or us mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!mainsite)(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @cesarcarlos Yes, you can hide it by specifically using mod_rewrite and remove the `,R=301` flag from the square brackets.

Comment: Unfortunately after testing this I found it causes another issue. This solution correctly redirects the main site, but now it also tries to redirect all the other sites hosted there. So now if I try to go to secondarysite.com I am automatically redirected to secondarysite.com/mainsite (which obviously doesn't exist). I'm trying to redirect only the main domain, but leave the rest of the domains pointing to their respective folders.

Comment: @cesarcarlos that shouldn't happen, since the condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]` says to apply the rule **ONLY** if the request host is mainsite.com

Comment: Ah OK, must be because I used the first one (RedirectMatch), will try with the second one. Just one more question, if my site is not .com but .fm, I'm assuming I should change .com$ to .fm$ in the RewriteCond line? Thanks, Jon!